# Transfer data from one column to a different column in a different table

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

I've got table A and table B in a database. I'm trying to move the column in table A to table B without losing any data. Not sure if its best to move the column somehow or make a whole new column in table B then copy the data over?

The problem is that the database is already in production and I don't want the clients to lose the data that is currently stored in column X in table A. I thought of making a migration to create the same column X in table B, and then somehow copying the data there. I am not sure how to do that, and I couldn't find a similar problem here.

Comment: Presumably you need to store the values into specific records? Or do you just need to transfer the values into new records in an empty table? Either `INSERT … SELECT` or an UPDATE with subselect might help.

Answer (score 1):

if you have phpmyadmin you can do this pretty easily. this command should work:

```
INSERT INTO `tabletwo.columnb` (SELECT 'columna' FROM tableone)
```

Always back up the dbs, load local and try this, never live lol. I'm sure your aware. :)

Note: columna and columnb are placeholder for your actual column names

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create the migration table to create de column on table B.

After you can use tinker ("php artisan tinker" on the terminal) to move the desired data on the table A to the B.